# When do invariant solutions of an SDE exist?

Tags: markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations, stationary-processes

I consider a one-dimensional SDE
$$
\mathrm d X_t = F(X_t) \mathrm d t + \sigma(X_t)\mathrm d B_t
$$
where $\mathbf P^{X_0} = \mu$ is the starting distribution, $F, \sigma: \mathbf R \to \mathbf R$. Let us assume that $X_t$ satisfies this SDE and is a timeinvariant Markov process. The main part of this question is:

> Can one determine under which conditions on $F$ and $\sigma$ there exists a $\mu$ such that $\mathbf P^{X_t} = \mu$ for all $t \geq 0$?

In addition I am also interested in determining $\mu$ (or rather: its density $\pi$ w.r.t. Lebesgue measure on $\mathbf R$) from $F$ and $\sigma$.
If I understand correctly this density would have to satisfy the following second-order differential equation given by the adjoint of the generator of $X_t$, i.e.

$$
0 = (\frac 1 2\sigma^2(x) \pi(x))'' - (F(x)\pi(x))'
$$
so I speculate that, given $\sigma$ and $F$, we can just solve this differential equation and ensure that $\pi$ is positive and integrates to $1$.

If we consdier for example the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process
$$
\mathrm d X_t = -\alpha X_t \mathrm dt + \sigma dB_t
$$
then we can easily guess and verify that $\mu = \mathcal N(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{2 \alpha})$ is such an invariant distribution and that its density fulfils above differential equation. However I have not been able to come up with another stationary Markov process based on playing around with the functions $F$ and $\sigma$ so examples of these would also be of interest to me.

Comment: https://eloecherbach.u-cergy.fr/cours.pdf  Chapter 3.

Comment: Thank you @Tobsn for that reference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of references

- (Stochastic Modelling and Applied Probability 66) Rafail Khasminskii (auth.)  Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations.
- ["Long-time dynamics of stochastic differential equations"](https://www.idpoisson.fr/berglund/kesm_notes.pdf)
- ["Ergodicity and speed of convergence to equilibrium for diffusion processes"](https://Ergodicity%20and%20speed%20of%20convergence%20to%20equilibrium%20for%20diffusion%20processes)
- ["Convergence of Markov Processes"](https://www.hairer.org/notes/Convergence.pdf) by Hairer
- ["Existence and uniqueness of martingale solutions for SDEs with rough or degenerate coefficients"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123607003709).
- "Invariant Distributions for Singular Stochastic Differential Equations"

In particular, in the last reference "Invariant Distributions for Singular Stochastic Differential Equations" by Cherny, they give conditions for degenerate coefficients $b,\sigma$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the long list of references (and the reply one year after I posted this question :)). Thm 3.1. was excatly what I was looking for.